# machine learning support vector machins(svm) model for predict

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, prediction, predict

im doing python code using machine learning support vector machins(svm) model for predict, i used a bank dataset from kaggle
so this is the code and the error dicated in the 4th row

```
`encoded_data = [0] * len(data_to_predict)
for i in range(len(data_to_predict)):
  if i == 0:
    encoded_data[i] = gen[data_to_predict[i]]
  elif i==1:
    encoded_data[i] = m[data_to_predict[i]]
  elif i==2:
    encoded_data[i] = ed[data_to_predict[i]]
  elif i==3:
     encoded_data[i] = s_emp[data_to_predict[i]]
  elif i==4:
     encoded_data[i] = d[data_to_predict[i]]
  elif i==10:
    encoded_data[i] = a[data_to_predict[i]]
  else:
    encoded_data[i] = s.fit_transform(np.array(encoded_data[i]).reshape(-1,1))`
```

this is the error why dose it shows 'male' what am i supposed to change or add??

```
`KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-e2388fb9ed49> in <module>
      2 for i in range(len(data_to_predict)):
      3   if i == 0:
----> 4     encoded_data[i] = gen[data_to_predict[i]]
      5   elif i==1:
      6     encoded_data[i] = m[data_to_predict[i]]


> KeyError: 'male'`
```

Answer (score 0):

what does your `data_to_predict` look like. What I understand from the provided information is  on this  line `encoded_data[i] = gen[data_to_predict[i]]` the `data_to_predict[i]` returns `'male'` and there is no key named `'male'` in `gen`.